# bottom submit button is overlapping the bootstrap footer on the content page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, coding-style

I have the following code on the _layout.cshtml page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Package</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/FeeCalc.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:cadetblue">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); width:100%; ">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
                        <a href="https://www.google.com">
                            <img src="~/Img/Logo_Circle.png" alt="QPR" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
    
                        </a>
                        <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">Test city</span><br />Test Company</span>
    
                    </span>
                    <span class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-5" style="font-size:19px;color:white;">Welcome,  @_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("FullName")</span>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="container-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <main role="main" class="pb-5">
                    @RenderBody()
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    
     
    
    @*    <footer class="bg-light footer text-center text-lg-start" style="height:20px" >
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:12px">
                © Copyright 2023 Test Company | Version 1.0
            </div>
        </footer>*@
    
        <footer class="bg-light text-center footer text-lg-start">
      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
                <span class="text-dark"> © Copyright 2023 Test Company | Version 1.0</span>
        
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->
    </footer>
    
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

My content page submit button is overlapping the footer. Not sure why it is doing that. below is the screen shot:

[image]
The red arrow is the "Submit" button partially hidden behind the footer. My content page has lot of

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col">
```

with input  text in between

below is the code for submit button

```
   <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px"  >
                    <input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
```

I want the footer width to be really less and I want the submit button to be seen clearly.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the padding of the main element? e.g. "pb-3" to "pb-5"

Comment: Try with this CSS code: 

input[type="submit"]{ 
display: inline-block; }